# How do I remap Shift+Space+Lbutton to Alt+Rbutton with AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to remap a software shortcut, namely <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Lbutton</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Rbutton</kbd>.

I tried this:

```
+SpaceLbutton::!Rbutton
```

I want to do a hold down and release.

Answer (score 0):

"Alt & RButton" behave like the "Shift & Space & Lbutton" combination of keys:

```
!RButton::
   Send, % "{ShiftDown}{Space Down}{LButton Down}{ShiftUp}"
   KeyWait, RButton
   Send, % "{Space Up}{LButton Up}"
   Return
```

And vice versa:

```
$+Space::
   KeyWait, LButton, % "DT.175" ; adjust waiting time here
   Send, % (b:=ErrorLevel) ? "{Space Down}":"{AltDown}{RButton Down}{AltUp}"
   KeyWait, Space
   Send, % b ? "{Space Up}":"{RButton Up}"
   Return
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i don't know why it's not working.

Comment: i removed the Lbutton and it's good to work with: +Space::!Rbutton . thanks again for help, i don't know what the % sign do in the send command.but will look for it :)